# How to prevent terraform from asking for the value of a variable that is set on AWS Secrets Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-secrets-manager

I have the following HCL code, that asks & reads the `secret_api_key` variable from the terminal on `terraform plan` and saves it in secret manager.

```
variable "secret_api_key" {
  type        = string
  sensitive   = true
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secret_api_key" {
  name = "secret_api_key"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secret_api_key" {
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret_api_key.id
  secret_string = var.secret_api_key
}
```

In another configuration, the secret is read like this:

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secret_api_key" {
  name       = "secret_api_key"
  depends_on = [aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret_api_key]
}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secret_api_key" {
  secret_id = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret_api_key.id
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "s3_to_service" {
  ...
  environment {
    variables = {
      SECRET_ARN = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secret_api_key.arn
    }
  }
}
```

---

How do I force terraform to **not** ask me for the API key everytime I plan? It needs to ask me the first time I do it, to store it at the secrets manager. But after that, it is redundant. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Provide some default value.

Comment: @Marcin I cannot hardcode a sensitive value as default. This code is uploaded on Git.

Comment: Only set up secret manager once then - separate them?

Comment: I mean, you provide a default value as an empty string, or whatever, and then program logic to get the value from SM, if real value is not given.

Comment: This leads to:
`# aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secret_api_key must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secret_api_key" {
      ~ secret_string  = (sensitive value) # forces replacement
    }`
It wants to replace the actual key with null values every-time I plan.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary This is a solution, but I am trying to see if there is a more clever way to do it

Comment: Not really - either you provide a value everytime or you don't but it will use the value at hand; reference the secret but don't try recreating the secret everytime. You can also pass in the value via the CLI if the problem is typing in input as opposed to getting input

Comment: Terraform works on calculating differences - if you provide nothing, it will assume that you want it cleared/removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really.

Either you manually provide a value every time or you don't but Terraform variables require a value specified in some shape, way, or form whether by you or by default, every time you want to evaluate a Terraform configuration.

If you plan/apply `aws_secretsmanager_secret`, there is no way around supplying a value manually unless you hard code a value or specify a default.

Terraform works based on calculating differences in the state - it needs to know what your expected state is (with your variable value) to then compare it with the actual state.

I would advise you to plan/apply the Terraform config for the secret when you want to create/update it & to separate the creation of the secret from the usage of the secret.

Then, you can use `data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret_api_key` to access it as you have.